# ErrorException: Undefined index: cedula Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

Cuando hago un post me sale este error

```
    ErrorException: Undefined index: cedula in file C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\app\Http\Controllers\AlumnoController.php on line 42
Stack trace:
  1. ErrorException-&gt;() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\app\Http\Controllers\AlumnoController.php:42
  2. Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions-&gt;handleError() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\app\Http\Controllers\AlumnoController.php:42
  3. App\Http\Controllers\AlumnoController-&gt;store() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:54
  4. call_user_func_array() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:54
  5. Illuminate\Routing\Controller-&gt;callAction() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php:45
  6. Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher-&gt;dispatch() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:212
  7. Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;runController() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:169
  8. Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;run() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:679
  9. Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:30
 10. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php:41
 11. Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings-&gt;handle() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 12. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 13. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php:58
 14. Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handle() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 15. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 16. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:104
 17. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:681
 18. Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRouteWithinStack() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:656
 19. Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRoute() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:622
 20. Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatchToRoute() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:611
 21. Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatch() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:176
 22. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:30
 23. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php:57
 24. Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies-&gt;handle() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 25. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 26. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php:31
 27. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 28. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 29. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php:31
 30. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 31. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 32. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php:27
 33. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize-&gt;handle() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 34. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 35. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:62
 36. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode-&gt;handle() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:151
 37. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:53
 38. Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:104
 39. Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:151
 40. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;sendRequestThroughRouter() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:116
 41. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;handle() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\public\index.php:55
 42. require_once() C:\Users\CITA\Documents\Projectos Externos\apirestlaravel\server.php:21
```

el post es correcto:

```
{
    "cedula" : "123asd",
    "nombre" : "juanito",
    "apellido" : "manoslargas",
    "email" : "juanito@gmial.com",
    "celular" : 123456789
}
```

Este es mi controlador AlumnoController, aqui capturo el post

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isJson()){
            $data = $request->json()->all();
            $alumno = Alumno::create([
                'cedula'=> $data['cedula'], //Esta es la linea 42
                'nombre'=> $data['nombre'],
                'apellido'=> $data['apellido'],
                'email'=> $data['email'],
                'celular'=> $data['celular']
            ]);
            return response()->json('sucess', 200);
            }
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorized'],401,[]);
    }
```

Este es mi Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('alumnos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('cedula')->unique();
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('apellido');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->integer('celular');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Creo que todo esta bien, no se que puede ser mi error

Comment: Supongo que porque `$data` es un objeto y no un array. Intenta con `$data->cedula;`

Comment: a veces me suele suceder esto, ahora volvi a intentar, no cambie nada mi peticion post y funciono. Uso postman para testear, pero a veces como lo mencione me devuelve este error y lo que hago es borrar y hacerlo de nuevo. Es raro